# For-loop with the dimension flexibility of broadcasting

Tags: julia

With the aid of broadcasting, the following code will work whether `x`, `y`, and `z` are scalars, vectors of size `n`, or any combination thereof.

```
b = zeros(n)
b .= x.*y.*z .+ x
```

However, I'd like a for-loop. The following for-loop only works when `x` is a vector of size `n`, `y` is a scalar, and `z` is a scalar.

```
for i = 1:n
    b[i] = x[i]*y*z + x[i]
end
```

To write the equivalent of `b .= x.*y.*z .+ x` as a for-loop for any case, I can only think of writing a for-loop for every combination of `x`, `y`, and `z` within if-statements. This can get messy with more variables in more complicated math expressions.

Is there a more elegant way to do what I'd like than using many if-statements?

Comment: Use a macro or a generated function.

Comment: What's the problem with using `broadcast`? The whole point of having it as a language feature is so that you can express complicated things like this in a way that's both concise and efficient.

Comment: I'd like to make it parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a wrapper type that indexing into it will give array indexing if wrapped variable is array and repeats the same value for all indices for scalars. I have an example below but it probably is not as efficient as using `broadcast`. And it is not checking if array lengths are consistent. However, a custom wrapper type would alleviate the situation.

```
julia> function f(x,y,z)
           lx,ly,lz = length(x),length(y),length(z)
           maxlen = max(lx,ly,lz)
           cx = cycle(x)
           cy = cycle(y)
           cz = cycle(z)
           b = zeros(maxlen)
           @inbounds for (xi,yi,zi,i) in zip(cx,cy,cz,1:maxlen)
               b[i] = xi*yi*zi+xi
           end
           return b
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1:3,21,2)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
  43.0
  86.0
 129.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is this not as efficient as broadcast?

Comment: It was just a guess. I did not time it comparatively. I just thought cycle iteration may cause inefficiency vs direct for-loop in broadcast.